# increase column value manual

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have id column in postgres which is not serial that is integer. It have 1 to 3 values while rows of this column more than 100. I want to assign values to empty rows as 4,5,6 continuously through query. This is example, while I have a lot of records in a table. So help me how to update an id column with a query

```
select id, name from xyz order by id;  

            id | name
            1  | a
            2  | b
            3  | c
               | d
               | e
               | f
```

wanted result

```
select id, name from xyz order by id;

    id | name
    1  | a
    2  | b
    3  | c
    4  | d
    5  | e
    6  | f
```

Below lines only for submit question please don't consider it:

```
select id ,name,date_time,(select 'wasa'::text) as link from abc 
union
select x.id+max(a.id),x.name,x.date_time,(select 'uu'::text) as link from xyz x ,abc a
group by x.id
order by id
```

Comment: Do you want to **permanently** update the table, or just assign those values when you retrieve the data?

Comment: Yes permanently

Comment: There is some sorting criteria for rows, where id's are null's ?

Comment: I want to update column

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(id) into temp_count 
from table_name ;

select id into temp_id
from table_name order by id asc limit 1;

while (temp_id <=temp_count)
Do
    set temp_last_id = (select id from table_name where id is not null order by id desc limit 1);
    update table_name
    set  id = temp_last_id +1;

    set temp_id =temp_id +1;
end while;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the maximum availabe value of id from table as

```
Select max(id) from xyz
```

suppose its value is 3. create a sequence and assign max value + 1 to is as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq START 4;
```

Update empty id using sequence as

```
Update xyz
SET id = nextval('seq')
WHERE id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single `update` statement:

```
update xyz
  set id = t.rn
from (
  select ctid, 
         row_number() over (order by name) + (select count(*) from xyz where id is not null) as rn
  from xyz
  where xyz.id is null
) t
where t.ctid = xyz.ctid;
```

Note that the "sequence" of the IDs is not guaranteed, but if you only want to generate a unique value it doesn't matter.